# Ruby on Rails and MAMP Pro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mamp

new to ruby, and rails... but not to the amp stack.

my preferred method for local development has always been to use MAMP Pro for it's ease of use and speed. but, i seem to have some more configuration to do if i want it to work with ROR.

i've got my server name setup (rails.dev) to use port 3000 and the disk location is set to the public folder of the rails installation.

http://rails.dev/ leads to a page that says 'Error establishing a database connection.'

what are the next steps?

any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you figured this out a long time ago. But for the sake of anyone just starting off I will provide an answer.

Rails uses [WEBrick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEBrick) Servers for local development.

In Rails 3

```
rails server
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

I am sure you can get rails to work with MAMP, but it is not idiomatic and is not going to be worth the trade-off.